# Detectar contorno de una tarjeta

Tags: android

Tengo que realizar una aplicación android que me permita detectar el contorno de una tarjeta con la ayuda de la cámara y después tomar la imagen, 
¿Saben si existe una librería o algún ejemplo que me pueda ayudar a realizar esta app?

Gracias por responder.
Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

OpenCv es una librería para el procesamiento de imágenes y vision artificial,  es compatible con Android, tal vez te puede servir. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Con [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) puedes meter elementos de visión artificial como la que indicas. Primero tendrás que aplicar un filtrado a la imagen, y luego aplicar un algoritmo de detección de bordes.

Ojo, no es la panacea, es una tarea complicada, y dependerá de iluminación, contraste, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Si es correcto lo que creo es que quieres detectar una tarjeta Sd (si no es corrígeme) si es eso porque no utilizas el método `environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()` o otro método environment con indicación External (Esto lo encuentras en la pagina oficial de android developers) que te ayude porque creo que hay otro que es uno que sirve como para detectar y el que te di yo es para buscar una ruta de la Sd y guardar o copiar archivos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder amigo. Me refiero a detectar el contorno de una credencial con la ayuda de la cámara. Algo parecido a esto http://productivity-blog.vanaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/real-time-edge-detection-ScanWritr.jpg